# Latex - Miktex cross references linking back to ref point

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, pdftex

Using pdftex i can  cross ref to a label say `\ref{label1}` for example. Clickin on it in the `.pdf` document you 'll be linked to the label. I'd like there to be a "back reference link" to the point that called `\ref{label1}`. Is this possible without adding another label to that point?
Thank you.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your question has nothing to to with MikTeX itself

Comment: Example: 
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,breaklinks,colorlinks,
citecolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue,
pdftitle={},
pdfauthor={Sotirios Chasapis},
pdfsubject={}]{hyperref}

 \begin{document}
\section{example1}
This is a link to \ref{sec:label2}

\section{example2}
THis is section 2. \label{sec:label2}
In the pdf document when somebody clicks on ref link being in section 1 comes here. I'd like here to be a link back to that ref point.

\end{document}

Comment: I think it has already been discussed: what if you use `\ref{label1}` twice in your document? Where would the link point? Better using the “Go back” feature of your PDF viewer.

Comment: I think this should be true `\hypertarget`... and `\hyperlink`, but the ambiguity remains, as egreg already stated